# Swift. How to write bytes from NSData into another NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, byte, nsdata

I'm trying to concatenate two `NSData` objects into one `NSMutableData`, and than get them back. For now i'm trying to do it in such way:

1. Get length of first object.
2. Write into `NSMutableData` in such order: first object length, first object, second object.

Code looks like:

```
let firstString = "first_string";
let secondString = "secondSting";

let firstData = firstString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
let secondData = secondString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!


let mutableData = NSMutableData()

var length = firstData.length

mutableData.appendBytes(&length, length: sizeof(Int))

mutableData.appendData(firstData)

mutableData.appendData(secondData)
```

Then I want to get datas back. So I suppose to read first data length and then get two datas.

```
    var length = 0
    mutableData.getBytes(&length, length: sizeof(Int))
```

But when I'm trying to get data I'm getting crash instead:

```
    var data = NSData()

    mutableData.getBytes(&data, range: NSMakeRange(sizeof(Int), length))
```

Maybe somebody know where is my problem or how to get datas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the data using `subdataWithRange()`:

```
let firstData1 = mutableData.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(sizeof(Int), length))
if let firstString1 = NSString(data: firstData1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
    println(firstString1)
} else {
    // bad encoding
}
```

Your solution

```
var data = NSData()
mutableData.getBytes(&data, range: NSMakeRange(sizeof(Int), length))
```

does not work and crashes because `NSData` is a reference type and
`data` a *pointer* to the object. You are overwriting this pointer
and the following bytes in memory.

Comment: Unless I have read it wrong, the question is how to concatenate two lots of data and before doing so begin the data with the length of the first data. This doesn't appear to answer that, it takes the data already formed and returns a subrange based on the sizeof(Int) and length. I don't see how this range has anything to do with what the question asks.

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow: From the question: *"Then I want to get datas back. ... But when I'm trying to get data I'm getting crash instead"* – As I understand the question, it is about extracting the data parts again. I sincerely hope that OP does not accept an answer if it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I misunderstood the question. Sorry. It threw me mixing UInt8 and Int, but I guess it works (safeguard against moving between 32-bit and 64-bit systems?).

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow: Yes, for transfer between 32-bit and 64-bit systems you should use a fixed-size type like `UInt64`, good point. And if Swift is ported to PowerPC then you should also use a fixed network byte order :)

Comment: One other thing that will need to be done in practical use is that the first byte needs to actually be read and for the length to be retrieved. Assumed by OP and repeated here is that the length is known beforehand and that's because the data is created and decoded in same place, but in real use that's unlikely to be the case.

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow: *"Assumed by OP and repeated here is that the length is known beforehand "* – This is not correct. OP retrieves the length back with `var length = 0; mutableData.getBytes(&length, length: sizeof(Int))`. My answer does not address the point because it seemed not to be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly without a crash in my storyboard. I just omitted the second `var` before `length` in order to avoid redefining it.

Here is the output for each line:

```
"first_string"
"secondSting"
<66697273 745f7374 72696e67>  // let firstData = ...
<7365636f 6e645374 696e67>    // let secondData = ...
<>                            // let mutableData = ...
12                            // var length = ...
// appending data
<0c000000 00000000>           
<0c000000 00000000 66697273 745f7374 72696e67>
<0c000000 00000000 66697273 745f7374 72696e67 7365636f 6e645374 696e67>
0                            // length = 0
<0c000000 00000000 66697273 745f7374 72696e67 7365636f 6e645374 696e67>
12                           // length
```

This means you probably have an error somewhere else. You did not redefine `length`, right?